# WebSocket connection with OpenShift DIY cartridge is dropped every 2 min

Tags: websocket, openshift

My application consists of two pieces: WebSocket server - which is hosted on OpenShift DIY cartridge; WebSocket client - which connects to my server from home PC. WebSocket server is written using embedded Jetty and its library for WebSockets. Client side is written using JAVA and Tyrus library. It works pretty well except for one glitch that I cannot explain.

When running WebSocket server on OpenShift DIY cartridge, WebSocket connection gets dropped every 2 min. Connection drops happen quite precisely so obviously it is not related to potential network outages. Besides I have tested exactly the same application on Heroku and there were no connection drop. Moreover onClose(...) method receives NORMAL_CLOSURE close code.

I am almost sure that OpenShift Apache layer closes idle WebSocket connections every 2 min. even though WebSocket client sends Ping messages and receives Pong messages from the server. Has anyone experienced this type of WebSocket connection drops? Are there are parameters I can use to prevent connection drops?

Thank you in advance.

**Update:** I added a dedicated thread on the server side to send Pong messages to the client (Jetty does not support Pong handlers yet so I cannot use Ping messages) and drops disappeared. It seems like OpenShift Apache layer started treating connection as "alive" and does not close it. Then I noticed one more strange behavior: someone ping my server side application via HTTPS every hour. HTTP headers look like this:
HTTP/1.1 HEAD /
Accept: */*
User-Agent: **Ruby**
X-Forwarded-Proto: **https**
X-Forwarded-Host: ....rhcloud.com
Connection: keep-alive
X-Request-Start: t=1409771442217677
X-Forwarded-For: **10.158.21.225**
Host: wsproxy-gimes4dieni.rhcloud.com
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Client-IP: 10.158.21.225
X-Forwarded-SSL-Client-Cert: (null)
X-Forwarded-Server: localhost

I do not use Ruby, I am using only HTTP and IP address is different from my regular requests. Does anybody has a clue whether this is some sort of OpenShift "service" of this is coming from the Internet?

Comment: I am experiencing kind of the same problem. I see in the log that my endpoints live well and send both ping and pong. They don't die. As soon as the application start communicating though (after some idle time), one of the endpoints will drop with a close code of 1006 ("closed abnormally").

Answer (score 0):

SSH into your project, open `~/haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg` with a text editor such as `vi` and edit `timeout queue`,`timeout client`, and `timeout server` to whatever you want. I set mine to `5m`, which is 5 minutes. After you have made the changes, exit and run

```
~/haproxy/bin/control restart
```

Now your websocket timeout should be set.